# Pandas : XLSX to CSV : extra comma generated as a first character

Tags: python, pandas, csv

I wrote a basic function to convert a xlsx file to a csv file. I am getting an extra `,` at the beginning of every CSV generated files. Do you know why and how to fix this issue?

Here is one example of a csv file generated with the code i wrote:

```
,0,First Name,Last Name,Gender,Country,Age,Date,Id
0,1,Dulce,Abril,Female,United States,32,15/10/2017,1562
1,2,Mara,Hashimoto,Female,Great Britain,25,16/08/2016,1582
2,3,Philip,Gent,Male,France,36,21/05/2015,2587
```

My code:

```
def generate_csv(xlsx_file_path, csv_file_path, csv_file_name):
    try: 
        data_xls = pd.read_excel(xlsx_file_path, 'Sheet1')
        data_xls.to_csv(csv_file_name,header=True, encoding = 'utf8')
        return ""
    except Exception as e:
        return str(e)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The code is working great. It seems that your first row (that corresponds to the headers) have the first column empty and that is why the ´,´ is added at the beginning.
Maybe you need to use ´data_xls.to_csv(csv_file_name,header=True, encoding = 'utf8',  index=False´) parameter to ignore the row numbers.

Comment: Works, amazing!